# Android Intent class not redirecting to desired activity

Tags: java, android

I try to redirect my app to activity_main3 with Intent but for some reason I can't figure out why it is redirecting to activity_main2. I have one button and a listView click event which are supposed to handle this transition correctly,I think they are linked with the correct ids   and the code compiles. Even debugger finds activity_main3 but the emulator still show the activity_main2. Do you have any idea?

References to the button and listView:

```
        textViewCities = findViewById(R.id.listViewFirestore);
        recyclerRedirect = findViewById(R.id.firestoreRecycler);
```

they exist on the respective xml files

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/firestoreRecycler"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/delAccount"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="testingRecyclerViewFirestore"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewFirestore"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/signOut"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.428" />
```

I need this button to send me to main_activity3 but it sends me the content of main_activity2

```
    recyclerRedirect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity3.class);
                d.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(d);
            }
        });
```

this listView click event that sends to main_activity2 works correctly.
Both  are instantiated in the first main activity under the method on create.

```
  textViewCities.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                clickedCity = (City)  adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);


                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("country", clickedCity.getCountry());
                bundle.putString("name", clickedCity.getName());
                bundle.putLong("population", clickedCity.getPopulation());


                Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                c.putExtras(bundle);
               startActivity(c);

            }
        });
```

image of logcats after clicking the button:

[image: x]

Comment: What the error? What's in logcat?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I added a screenshots of the logcats                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAOYD.png

Comment: Have you logged in the button click and `onCreate` of Activity 3 to confirm they are being called as expected? What does MainActivity3 look like?